# Normalise positively skewed data with heavy tailed distribution

Tags: r, skew, normalization

I am trying to figure out how to normalised some positively skewed data.
[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyU5R.png)
I really need it to have some parvence of positive distribution, but I have already tried log-transforming and it simply does not work. I get this kind of distribution. 
[log.data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9mhU.png)
I also tried sqrt(), but still no joy.
Should I just get rid of some of the extreme values on the tail? Why is log() not really doing much in terms of normalising my data?

Answer (score 0):

Log transforming your data won't necessarily make it unskewed, but it does reduce the data range in the axis it was applied. [Read this paper about using log transformations.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4120293/)

Nevertheless, a simple log transformation formatted your x-axis from a 1.2 e+07 range to a 0.2 range according to your image.